# What useful macros have you created in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, macros

I use Netbeans (nightly build) for Ruby on Rails development and I'm looking to beef up my macros. I've created a few myself:

copy identifier:

```
select-identifier copy-to-clipboard
```

paste clipboard over identifier:

```
select-identifier paste-from-clipboard
```

double quote element

```
select-element-next "\""
```

single quote element:

```
select-element-next "'"
```

But I'm looking for other useful ones and Google is giving me nothing.
The record macro feature usually doesn't work too well so I'd rather just "write" the macros myself but I can't even find a reference that lists what commands (like "select-identifier") are actually available.

Any Netbeans macro gurus out there?

Comment: Not many yet, by the look of it :-) I wonder if this means (1) you don't need them because NetBeans is so good already; or (2) it's too hard to do this in NetBeans. Not passing judgment, I've never used it (I'm an Eclipse man, through and through).

Comment: I was an Eclipse man too when I was working with Java; I loved it. But Eclipse for RoR is just not on the same level as Netbeans IMO.

Comment: I've been using netbeans for 2 years now and I can't believe I hadn't noticed the macros before. It's going to help with repetitive tasks for sure. Judging from my own experience I think that most macros will be tailor made for a particular situation by its author.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEditorMacros) is a list of macro codes with short explanations. Might be useful for someone.

**Update:** replaced old link with one to the Netbeans site and included the macro list in here.

```
abbrev-debug-line   Debug Filename and Line Number
adjust-caret-bottom Move Insertion Point to Bottom
adjust-caret-center Move Insertion Point to Center
adjust-caret-top    Move Insertion Point to Top
adjust-window-bottom    Scroll Insertion Point to Bottom
adjust-window-center    Scroll Insertion Point to Center
adjust-window-top   Scroll Insertion Point to Top
all-completion-show Show All Code Completion Popup
annotations-cycling Annotations Cycling
beep    Beep
build-popup-menu    Build Popup Menu
build-tool-tip  Build Tool Tip
caret-backward  Insertion Point Backward
caret-begin Insertion Point to Beginning of Document
caret-begin-line    Insertion Point to Beginning of Text on Line
caret-begin-word    Insertion Point to Beginning of Word
caret-down  Insertion Point Down
caret-end   Insertion Point to End of Document
caret-end-line  Insertion Point to End of Line
caret-end-word  Insertion Point to End of Word
caret-forward   Insertion Point Forward
caret-line-first-column Insertion Point to Beginning of Line
caret-next-word caret-next-word
caret-previous-word caret-previous-word
caret-up    Insertion Point Up
collapse-all-code-block-folds   Collapse All Java Code
collapse-all-folds  Collapse All
collapse-all-javadoc-folds  Collapse All Javadoc
collapse-fold   Collapse Fold
comment Comment
complete-line   Complete Line
complete-line-newline   Complete Line and Create New Line
completion-show Show Code Completion Popup
copy-selection-else-line-down   Copy Selection else Line down
copy-selection-else-line-up Copy Selection else Line up
copy-to-clipboard   Copy
cut-to-clipboard    Cut
cut-to-line-begin   Cut from Insertion Point to Line Begining
cut-to-line-end Cut from Insertion Point to Line End
default-typed   Default Typed
delete-next Delete Next Character
delete-previous Delete Previous Character
documentation-show  Show Documentation Popup
dump-view-hierarchy Dump View Hierarchy
expand-all-code-block-folds Expand All Java Code
expand-all-folds    Expand All
expand-all-javadoc-folds    Expand All Javadoc
expand-fold Expand Fold
fast-import Fast Import
find-next   Find Next Occurrence
find-previous   Find Previous Occurrence
find-selection  Find Selection
first-non-white Go to First Non-whitespace Char
fix-imports Fix Imports
format  Format
generate-code   Insert Code
generate-fold-popup Generate Fold Popup
generate-goto-popup Generate Goto Popup
generate-gutter-popup   Margin
goto    Go to Line...
goto-declaration    Go to Declaration
goto-help   Go to Javadoc
goto-implementation Go to Implementation
goto-source Go to Source
goto-super-implementation   Go to Super Implementation
in-place-refactoring    Instant Rename
incremental-search-backward Incremental Search Backward
incremental-search-forward  Incremental Search Forward
insert-break    Insert Newline
insert-date-time    Insert Current Date and Time
insert-tab  Insert Tab
introduce-constant  Introduce Constant...
introduce-field Introduce Field...
introduce-method    Introduce Method...
introduce-variable  Introduce Variable...
java-next-marked-occurrence Navigate to Next Occurrence
java-prev-marked-occurrence Navigate to Previous Occurrence
jump-list-last-edit Last edit
jump-list-next  Forward
jump-list-prev  Back
last-non-white  Go to Last Non-whitespace Char
make-getter Replace Variable With its Getter
make-is Replace Variable With its is* Method
make-setter Replace Variable With its Setter
match-brace Insertion Point to Matching Brace
move-selection-else-line-down   Move Selection else Line down
move-selection-else-line-up Move Selection else Line up
org.openide.actions.PopupAction Show Popup Menu
page-down   Page Down
page-up Page Up
paste-formated  Paste Formatted
paste-from-clipboard    Paste
redo    Redo
reindent-line   Re-indent Current Line or Selection
remove-line Delete Line
remove-line-begin   Delete Preceding Characters in Line
remove-selection    Delete Selection
remove-tab  Delete Tab
remove-trailing-spaces  Remove Trailing Spaces
remove-word-next    remove-word-next
remove-word-previous    remove-word-previous
replace Replace
run-macro   Run Macro
scroll-down Scroll Down
scroll-up   Scroll Up
select-all  Select All
select-element-next Select Next Element
select-element-previous Select Previous Element
select-identifier   Select Identifier
select-line Select Line
select-next-parameter   Select Next Parameter
select-word Select Word
selection-backward  Extend Selection Backward
selection-begin Extend Selection to Beginning of Document
selection-begin-line    Extend Selection to Beginning of Text on Line
selection-begin-word    Extend Selection to Beginning of Word
selection-down  Extend Selection Down
selection-end   Extend Selection to End of Document
selection-end-line  Extend Selection to End of Line
selection-end-word  Extend Selection to End of Word
selection-first-non-white   Extend Selection to First Non-whitespace Char
selection-forward   Extend Selection Forward
selection-last-non-white    Extend Selection to Last Non-whitespace Char
selection-line-first-column Extend Selection to Beginning of Line
selection-match-brace   Extend Selection to Matching Brace
selection-next-word selection-next-word
selection-page-down Extend Selection to Next Page
selection-page-up   Extend Selection to Previous Page
selection-previous-word selection-previous-word
selection-up    Extend Selection Up
shift-line-left Shift Line Left
shift-line-right    Shift Line Right
split-line  Split Line
start-macro-recording   Start Macro Recording
start-new-line  Start New Line
stop-macro-recording    Stop Macro Recording
switch-case Switch Case
to-lower-case   To Lowercase
to-upper-case   To Uppercase
toggle-case-identifier-begin    Switch Capitalization of Identifier
toggle-comment  Toggle Comment
toggle-highlight-search Toggle Highlight Search
toggle-line-numbers Toggle Line Numbers
toggle-non-printable-characters Toggle Non-printable Characters
toggle-toolbar  Toggle Toolbar
toggle-typing-mode  Toggle Typing Mode
tooltip-show    Show Code Completion Tip Popup
uncomment   Uncomment
undo    Undo
word-match-next Next Matching Word
word-match-prev Previous Matching Word
```

Comment: That's perfect! BUT I've since switched to Rubymine :)

Answer (score 9):

I needed to surround text fragments with HTML tags, but couldn't figure out how to do it quickly, so I came up with this macro:

```
cut-to-clipboard "<strong>" paste-from-clipboard "</strong>"
```

Simple, clean, and you can put any tag/text you want. Give it a shortcut like Alt+B and you have quick way to insert HTML

Answer (score 7):

for php add semicolon to end line ("complete line")
but keep your cursor at the current point, 
so you can keep typing the rest of the line

```
split-line
caret-down
caret-end-line ";" 
caret-begin-line 
selection-begin-line remove-selection 
delete-previous
```

Comment: I do it this way:   ";" delete-previous caret-end-line ";" jump-list-last-edit jump-list-last-edit

Answer (score 2):

This is my first netbeans macro.

"echo '< pre >';print_r();die();"

my shortcut key => Alt+A

for this you can use any shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Oh well, just experimenting with netbeans.

I add a simple new macro for netbeans.
name: "scrollup_newline"
code:
  insert-break
  scroll-up

It works well, so every i press enter, the editor move one line down. This way i can code and have the caret in the middle of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is for HTML. I just made:

```
caret-begin-line "<li>" caret-end-line "</li>" caret-down
```

Mapped it to ctrl+shift+L This is my first netbeans macro. Later maybe I can make it work for an entire selection somehow.

Edit: Can't figure out doing it for selections, but adding "caret-down" at the end was almost as good.

Comment: add `cut-to-clipboard` before and `paste-from-clipboard` in place of your `caret-end-line`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the macro I wrote today. I am very much missing an "extract method" or "introduce method" refactoring in PHP, so I wrote this macro. I know this is far less complex than the refactorings in Java, but it can be used and it saves a few copy/pastes and writing repetitive code.

```
cut-to-clipboard
"$this->UNNAMED_METHOD();"
collapse-fold
caret-end-line caret-backward caret-end-line insert-break
"private function UNNAMED_METHOD() {"insert-break
paste-from-clipboard insert-break
```

Comment: You should try Jetbrains PHPStorm. It has a bunch of refactorings, including Extract Method and Introduce Variable.

Comment: Jetbrains PHPStorm is commercial. I prefer open-souce projects. I will, however take a look at it, I tried  some time ago but I was not impressed.

Answer (score 1):

This macro inserts `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixed equivalents of a css3 style rule:

```
caret-end-line selection-begin-line copy-to-clipboard caret-backward insert-break caret-up "-webkit-" paste-from-clipboard insert-break "-moz-" paste-from-clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert-date-time remove-word-previous remove-word-previous
```

Mapped to CTRL+SHIFT+D to insert the short date, so useful cause I like to date my comments / TODOs but often don't know the date!

Although I think Code Templates and more useful, for example:

```
           // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="${cursor}">
```

and

```
           // </editor-fold>
```

Mapped to 'fold' then tab and 'endfold' then tab respectively.

Also

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "${EXP default="Got here"}");
```

Mapped to 'jop' then tab is handy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient but it helps me out lol

```
"(() ? : );"
caret-backward
caret-backward
caret-backward
caret-backward
caret-backward
caret-backward
caret-backward
caret-backward
```

As one can see, this is for PHP quick conditionals. This then places the cursor in the spot where you start typing the condition. Perfect no matter where your throwing it into. I put this to Ctrl+NUMPAD0 for quick typing access. I orignally had it to two TABs but that quickly got annoying haha

Answer (score 0):

I often like to have commas as the first character separating properties or list items in JavaScript; like so:

```
var foo = {
    a : 'a'
    //, b : 'B' //todo: make lcase
    , c : 'c'
};
```

Sometimes, I either forget to do this, or have a mass of text to update. To fix these quickly, I bound the keyboard shortcut `C-, C-,` -- That's two presses of ',' while holding CTRL key -- to:

```
caret-end-line selection-next-word selection-next-word " " caret-backward caret-backward insert-break
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Code Templates to be very useful, especially this one (for HTML):

```
<${tag}>${cursor}</${tag}>
```

The abbreviation is "tt", and it can also surround any text with custom tag, when called by the code template menu.

```
<${param_name default="tag"}${cursor}>
${selection}
</${param_name default="tag"}>
```

This one will surround anything with any tag. Select something, then Alt+F3, then just select this template from the menu. After that type the tag you want, e.g. "div".

Comment: While it is a good example of a code template, OP asked for macros.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code template for creating a static logger in a class using SLF4J. I tie it to "Log".

```
private static final ${loggerType type="org.slf4j.Logger" default="Logger" editable="false"} log = ${loggerFactoryType type="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" default="LoggerFactory" editable="false"}.getLogger(${classType editable="false" currClassName default="getClass()"}.class);
```

This makes a log.debug line which I tie to "log":

```
log.debug("${message}", "${variables}");
```

Comment: While it is a good example of a code template, OP asked for macros.