# Netbeans: Apply HTML code on highlighted text

Tags: netbeans, ide

Is it possible to apply HTML code on highlighted text like in Zend Studio 5?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>Open preferences -> Editor -> Macros (in version 6.9.1)</del>

Open Tools > Options > Editor > Macros (in version 8.0.1)

Add a new macro called something like "html-bold", then hightlight it. Paste this in the Macro Code section:

```
cut-to-clipboard "<b>" paste-from-clipboard "</b>"
```

Set a shortcut if you want. I tried it with CTRL+B and it worked fine.

Note that it will replace the current contents of your clipboard with the text you selected.

To learn more about Netbeans macros, see [What useful macros have you created in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567815/what-useful-macros-have-you-created-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

On the MacOSX version (8.0.2), the Macros editor is still in the 6.9.1 location (Preferences->Editor->Macros).

The above works well, although I had to use Ctrl-Alt- as my meta key sequence, since MacOSX assigns some of the other more convenient ones.